# ArgumentError (too few arguments): when calling format.json on rails 4.04

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-3.2, rubygems

When executing

```
format.json{render json: {}, status: :ok}
```

in Rails 4.0.4, I get the following error:

```
ArgumentError (too few arguments):
```

Although I have another program (with Rails 3.2.13) where the exact same line executes with no problem. am I missing something here?

any gems?

or change in syntax with rails 4?

Answer (score 92, accepted):

Mostly you would get the error `ArgumentError (too few arguments):` on the `format` when you forget to call this part of code within the block to `respond_to` method call.

Your code should actually look like

```
def action_name
  respond_to do |format|  ## Add this
    format.json { render json: {}, status: :ok}
    format.html 
    ## Other format
  end                    ## Add this
end
```